# Overlay Image Website Tour

Tags: jquery, user-interface, interface

Need to add a help image that can be turned on and off for a UI project I am working on. I cant find anyone that has done this on a website but it is used on apps all the time. I heard SVG or jquery might be the way to go but still haven't found a great to tutorial explain how. Can anyone help?

you can see an example here http://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/uploads/legacy/educate-users-about-apps/Float_Reader.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## have a look at this jquery plugin

http://usablica.github.io/intro.js/

## example

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Without Bullets</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Intro.js - Better introductions for websites and features with a step-by-step guide for your projects.">
    <meta name="author" content="Afshin Mehrabani (@afshinmeh) in usabli.ca group">

    <!-- styles -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Add IntroJs styles -->
    <link href="../../introjs.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-narrow">

      <div class="masthead">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right" data-step="5" data-intro="Get it, use it.">
          <li><a href="https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/tags"><i class='icon-black icon-download-alt'></i> Download</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://github.com/usablica/intro.js">Github</a></li>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com/usablica">@usablica</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="muted">Intro.js</h3>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 data-step="1" data-intro="This is a tooltip!">Without Bullets</h1>
        <p class="lead" data-step="4" data-intro="Another step.">This is the basic usage of IntroJs, with <code>data-step</code> and <code>data-intro</code> attributes.</p>
        <a class="btn btn-large btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:introJs().setOption('showBullets', false).start();">Show me how</a>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="row-fluid marketing">
        <div class="span6" data-step="2" data-intro="Ok, wasn't that fun?" data-position='right'>
          <h4>Section One</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>

          <h4>Section Two</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>

          <h4>Section Three</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>
          </div>

        <div class="span6" data-step="3" data-intro="More features, more fun."  data-position='left'>
          <h4>Section Four</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>

          <h4>Section Five</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>

          <h4>Section Six</h4>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis augue a neque cursus ac blandit orci faucibus. Phasellus nec metus purus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../intro.js"></script> <!-- wherever the plugin is -->
  </body>
</html>
```

## if you don't like this one then theres some alternatives

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-awesome-jquery-site-tour-plugins-for-guiding-users-with-style/